# python create nested directory based on two lists

Tags: python, list

Good morning,

This might be easy but I´m just starting with python. For learning:
Is there are 'cleaner' way creating a nested dict based on two lists than this:

```
person = ['mama.a','mama.b', 'mama.c',
         'mama.d', 'papa.a', 'papa.b']
kind = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
combined = {}

# GOAL:
# {'mama': {'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': [], 'd': []}, 'papa': {'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': [], 'd': []}}

for human in [i.split('.')[0] for i in person]:
    combined[human] = {}
    for attrib in kind:
        combined[human][attrib] = []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about making a `set` of the names. To ensure you only try to add each one to `dict` once.

```
combined = {}
for n in set(p.split('.')[0] for p in person):
    combined[n] = {k:[] for k in kind}
```

This could probably be made into a monster one-liner nested `dict` comprehension. Although I dont think it would be as easy to read.

or you could split the `set` out onto another line. It then becomes

```
pset = set(p.split('.')[0] for p in person)
pdict = {p: {k: [] for k in kind} for p in pset}
```

Where the second line is the same as @Faiz Haldes answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
{p.split('.')[0]: {k: [] for k in kind} for p in person}
```

Comment: its very easy to cross the boundary between readability and concise in python, and I'd suggest you to always be with readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
combined = {x.split('.')[0]:{i:[] for i in kind} for x in person} #if you require no check as to whether mama or papa contain a, b, c, or d
print combined

neutral = {i.split('.')[0]:[n.split('.')[1] for n in person if n.split('.')[0] == i.split('.')[0]] for i in person} #if you require a check
combined = {k:{v:[] for v in neutral[k]} for k in neutral}
print combined
```